# How to use PHP code with wordpress page

Tags: php, customization, pages

new user to WP.
I am dynamically creating HTML tables with SQL data in my PHP.
WordPress pages do not allow PHP code, and I've been hounded by individuals not to use a PHP plugin due to security reasons.

Now if i just needed to run a PHP file i would simply include it inside of my custom page-template. Since the code needs to be displayed inside the "content container" (which is dynamically loaded) I don't fully understand where to place my code.

```
<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>
```

I've noticed this code above is calling the content container for that page.
Should i be loading a different page here? or should i be directly modifying the page data inside the DB to reflect my php? will this work?
whats the best thing to do in my situation?

Comment: "I've been hounded by individuals not to use a PHP plugin due to security reasons." If you are refering to Wordpress plugins (PHP plugins, basically), I don't know why someone told you that, but it's wrong.

Comment: I was told not to use php plugins because it enables users to enter potentially harmful php code into user inputs/ comments. Do you have a plugin you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to create dynamic data outputs really depends on the what, why, and how.

For example, if you're creating a theme that creates its own custom post type, say, to store information about the head honchos that run the business behind the site, then just create a "single-$CPTNAME.php" template that has the code that you want.

Another method of doing this would be to create a custom template, and simply select that for a given page.  See [the WordPress Page Templates documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) for more information on how to create the custom templates and make them selectable in the WordPress admin UI.

Comment: I need a page that will take SQL data, create custom fields, display those custom fields in a HTML table. no user input. Need this data displayed in the content container area of default template. that is not possible?

so what you are saying is basically i need to modify a custom template to create the HTML table/ sql calls on my wordpress page?

Comment: Of course I don't have a full picture of what you need: I can't give you a perfect answer on so little info. I can say that there are ways to do it; but if this is to pull from another system altogether then a plugin that creates a widget or WP shortcode which can be embedded into a page or post seems best.

Comment: I was aware of using a custom templates before hand i just thought there could be a different way that would involve less design work.

 I've decided to go with the custom template method, less coding for me, more work for the design guys :P
thanks anyway dude.